# Heroku python app throwing error - KeyError: 'pip._vendor.urllib3.util.queue'

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, pip

I am getting below error while deploying my application on Heroku. Previously it was working fine but now giving this error.

Running same application on Linux Virtual environment with same python version is working fine.

```
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055457+00:00 app[web.1]: importlib.import_module(package)
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055459+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055458+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055460+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055462+00:00 app[web.1]: from .deprecated import resolve_model_name
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055463+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/deprecated.py", line 8, in <module>
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055464+00:00 app[web.1]: from .cli import download
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055466+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055467+00:00 app[web.1]: from .download import download
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055468+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 9, in <module>
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055469+00:00 app[web.1]: from .link import link_package
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055471+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/cli/link.py", line 4, in <module>
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055473+00:00 app[web.1]: import pip
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055474+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055475+00:00 app[web.1]: from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055478+00:00 app[web.1]: from pip.download import path_to_url
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055479+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 40, in <module>
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055481+00:00 app[web.1]: from pip._vendor import requests, six
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055483+00:00 app[web.1]: from . import packages
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055485+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages.py", line 12, in <module>
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055486+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.modules['pip._vendor.requests.packages.' + mod] = sys.modules["pip._vendor." + mod]
2018-08-23T06:40:34.055538+00:00 app[web.1]: **KeyError: 'pip._vendor.urllib3.util.queue'**
2018-08-23T06:40:34.057109+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-08-23 06:40:34 +0000] [13] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13)
2018-08-23T06:40:34.191433+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-08-23 06:40:34 +0000] [10] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-08-23T06:40:34.191660+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-08-23 06:40:34 +0000] [10] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Answer (score 0):

switching from from `pip._vendor import requests` to `import requests` solved this issue for me. If it doesnt solve it for you, you should check the version of pip u are using, apparently i can reproduce this issue when im using pip 10+, so try downgrading to pip 9.